# In POSIX, is there a way to use a condition variable with a read-lock mutex?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, condition-variable

`pthread_cond_wait` accepts only a `pthread_mutex_t` but I have a data structure (multiple reader, multiple writer queue, with peeking) in which I'd like to use a reader/writer mutex for efficiency (Allow parallel reading of data). I use POSIX condition variables to block readers and writers when the queue is empty or full respectively.

Is there a built-in equivalent to condition variables that accepts a reader/writer mutex (maybe not in `pthread.h`, for instnace, semaphores are not there) or a good practice pattern in usage of mutexes to accomplish this?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, there is no such a thing you are asking for. Besides it's not clear when do you remove items from the queue, please explain your design.

Comment: @NickZavaritsky: The queue was not important. I just mentioned it for context. From the other linked question, it seems like the POSIX people didn't do their job and decided to appeal to common sense with vague prose instead. Thanks for answering.

Comment: on the countrary I consider your queue design very much important. It looks like it is impossible to implement with the single rwlock. Also please note that mutexes and condition variables are the building blocks for other primitives; there is even special support in Linux kernel to make them fast (futex interfaces). Acquiring rwlock already involves locking a few mutexes internally. Just add another mutex to wait on the condition variable.